# line-height doesn't vertically center inline-block

Tags: html, css

I tried to vertically center an inline-block like this:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  line-height: 50px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

But the span is not vertically centered. Why?

Answer (score 2):

Because `line-height` sets the position of the baseline of your text (the bottom end of your `span`). Since your span is `20px` high you must add half of that to `line-height`:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  line-height: 60px;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's still not centered. There's 16px above the span and 14px below.